# OpenH264 won't work properly on Waterfox, what am I missing?

Tags: firefox, h.264, html5, waterfox

All the boxes on https://www.youtube.com/html5 appear to be ticked and yet mp4 youtube videos fail to load. The changes I have made so far to about:config I shall list here:

```
media.fragmented-mp4.enabled              True  
media.fragmented-mp4.exposed              True
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.autoupdate          True
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled             True
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version             1.2
media.mediasource.enabled                 True
media.mediasource.ignore_codecs           True
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.provider.enabled    True
```

I used the instructions in http://www.legitwebs.com/install-openh264-firefox/ to help install the files manually and I have tested it with all other plugins and add-ons disabled with no success. Any ideas on what I can try next or is this a known problem with Waterfox?

EDIT: forgot to mention that this is on Waterfox version 34.0.1

Comment: What OS?  Could this be an issue of a 32-bit plugin or codec not working on a 64-bit browser?

Comment: Windows 8 64bit. That could be the problem, I'll check if there's anything that explicitly says that openh264 doesn't work with 64bit.

Comment: I made sure this time it was the 64bit release of openh264, no success.